# Generating UI to test Web Service Operation

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I am creating basic .NET webpages as a UI, to invoke WCF service and display the result. I feel many web developers must have come across this situation, earlier.

Is there any existing tool out there, which could take WSDL as input and generate input fields either in HTML or .NET webpages.

Comment: I don't know about HTML or .NET webpage, but I do use a windows app to test my web services named _Visual Web Service Client_.  Should be able to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a service from a web page is definetely a bad practice.

Depending of your service, there are many tools available like WcfTestClient, soapUI, WCFStorm, ... but is also a bad usage.

From my point of view, you will never find any better tool than your favorite unit test framework. The test client, nor soapUI will create a test that can run in a Continuous Integration scenario.

Comment: thanks for pointing out about continuous limitation in case of continuous integration scenario.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a tool named storm that I read about but I don't have direct experience with.

http://storm.codeplex.com/